# Magento 2 REST API : How do I get pending orders using API?

Tags: magento2, orders, api

I wonder how do I get **pending orders using Magento API** with OAuth token?

Thank you,

UPDATED

If I try as follows,

```
public function index2()
{           
    $consumerKey = 'kfkhypveth1upv6f4uwy5l9r7tdwmdp0';
    $consumerSecret = 't9ire4rup8wre5gbbqt3ic2q2snb6ogs';
    $accessToken = '9alfh5bntatd0gk3lwdjxv972erppnmk';
    $accessTokenSecret = 'rxmvwjrb9r8qq2hy0e2ijdytk2srrhmc';        
    $method = 'GET';
    $status_field     = "searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=status";
    $status_value     =  "searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=pending";//
    $status_condition = "searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq";       
    $sc = $status_field . '&' . $status_value . '&' . $status_condition;

    $url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/mg1/index.php/rest/V1/orders/?".$sc;

    $data = [
            'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumerKey,
            'oauth_nonce' => md5(uniqid(rand(), true)),
            'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
            'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
            'oauth_token' => $accessToken,
            'oauth_version' => '1.0',
    ];

    $data['oauth_signature'] = $this->sign($method, $url, $data, $consumerSecret, $accessTokenSecret);      
    $curl = curl_init();        
    curl_setopt_array($curl, [
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
                    'Authorization: OAuth ' . http_build_query($data, '', ',')
            ]
    ]);

    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    echo '<pre>';       
    print_r(json_decode($result,false));        


 }//end of function
```

I get following error,

```
stdClass Object
(
[message] => Invalid signature
[trace] => #0 C:\wamp64\www\mg1\vendor\magento\framework\Oauth\Oauth.php(121): Magento\Framework\Oauth\Oauth->_validateSignature(Array, 't9ire4rup8wre5g...', 'GET', 'http://127.0.0....', 'rxmvwjrb9r8qq2h...')
#1 C:\wamp64\www\mg1\vendor\magento\module-webapi\Model\Authorization\OauthUserContext.php(82): Magento\Framework\Oauth\Oauth->validateAccessTokenRequest(Array, 'http://127.0.0....', 'GET')
#2 C:\wamp64\www\mg1\vendor\magento\module-authorization\Model\CompositeUserContext.php(78): Magento\Webapi\Model\Authorization\OauthUserContext->getUserId()
#3 C:\wamp64\www\mg1\vendor\magento\module-authorization\Model\CompositeUserContext.php(57): Magento\Authorization\Model\CompositeUserContext->getUserContext()
#4 C:\wamp64\www\mg1\vendor\magento\module-webapi\Model\WebapiRoleLocator.php(45): Magento\Authorization\Model\CompositeUserContext->getUserId()
#5 C:\wamp64\www\mg1\vendor\magento\framework\Authorization.php(47): Magento\Webapi\Model\WebapiRoleLocator->getAclRoleId()
#6 C:\wamp64\www\mg1\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\Authorization->isAllowed('Magento_Sales::...', NULL)
#7 C:\wamp64\www\mg1\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\Authorization\Interceptor->___callParent('isAllowed', Array)
#8 C:\wamp64\www\mg1\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'isAllowed', Object(Magento\Framework\Authorization\Interceptor), Array, 'customerAuthori...')
#9 C:\wamp64\www\mg1\vendor\magento\module-customer\Model\Plugin\CustomerAuthorization.php(58): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}('Magento_Sales::...', NULL)
 #10 C:\wamp64\www\mg1\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(67): Magento\Customer\Model\Plugin\CustomerAuthorization->aroundIsAllowed(Object(Magento\Framework\Authorization\Interceptor), Object(Closure), 'Magento_Sales::...', NULL)
#11 C:\wamp64\www\mg1\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'isAllowed', Object(Magento\Framework\Authorization\Interceptor), Array, 'guestAuthorizat...')
#12 C:\wamp64\www\mg1\vendor\magento\module-webapi\Model\Plugin\GuestAuthorization.php(38): Magento\Framework\Authorization\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}('Magento_Sales::...', NULL)
#13 C:\wamp64\www\mg1\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Webapi\Model\Plugin\GuestAuthorization->aroundIsAllowed(Object(Magento\Framework\Authorization\Interceptor), Object(Closure), 'Magento_Sales::...')
#14 C:\wamp64\www\mg1\var\generation\Magento\Framework\Authorization\Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\Authorization\Interceptor->___callPlugins('isAllowed', Array, Array)
#15 C:\wamp64\www\mg1\vendor\magento\framework\Webapi\Authorization.php(37): Magento\Framework\Authorization\Interceptor->isAllowed('Magento_Sales::...')
#16 C:\wamp64\www\mg1\vendor\magento\module-webapi\Controller\Rest\RequestValidator.php(86): Magento\Framework\Webapi\Authorization->isAllowed(Array)
#17 C:\wamp64\www\mg1\vendor\magento\module-webapi\Controller\Rest\RequestValidator.php(70): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\RequestValidator->checkPermissions()
#18 C:\wamp64\www\mg1\vendor\magento\module-webapi\Controller\Rest\InputParamsResolver.php(80): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\RequestValidator->validate()
#19 C:\wamp64\www\mg1\vendor\magento\module-webapi\Controller\Rest.php(299): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\InputParamsResolver->resolve()
#20 C:\wamp64\www\mg1\vendor\magento\module-webapi\Controller\Rest.php(216): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->processApiRequest()
#21 C:\wamp64\www\mg1\var\generation\Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor.php(37): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 C:\wamp64\www\mg1\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(135): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
 #23 C:\wamp64\www\mg1\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
 #24 C:\wamp64\www\mg1\index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap-    >run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#25 {main}
```

)

But if I change the url as

```
 $url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/mg1/index.php/rest/V1/orders/1";
```

then I get first order details.

Any idea why?

Comment: Did you know how to work with OAuth-based authentication Magento 2?

Comment: I already have implemented OAuth and have saved access token in a table. Using this I wanted to get pending orders.

Comment: You should try with GET: `http://<magento_host>/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=status&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=pending&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use these samples to do all things that you want using the API. There are 3 different methods, you can use anyone of these 3 methods.

> Remember to change the URL and method to what you want to do.

**API REST using OAuth based authentication**

```
<?php
function sign($method, $url, $data, $consumerSecret, $tokenSecret)
{
    $url = urlEncodeAsZend($url);

    $data = urlEncodeAsZend(http_build_query($data, '', '&'));
    $data = implode('&', [$method, $url, $data]);

    $secret = implode('&', [$consumerSecret, $tokenSecret]);

    return base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $data, $secret, true));
}

function urlEncodeAsZend($value)
{
    $encoded = rawurlencode($value);
    $encoded = str_replace('%7E', '~', $encoded);
    return $encoded;
}

// REPLACE WITH YOUR ACTUAL DATA OBTAINED WHILE CREATING NEW INTEGRATION
$consumerKey = '1fuj3asjsk4w3qb3cx44ik5ue188s30s';
$consumerSecret = 'lcey0h5uyt26slvtws5okaiqh8ojju5d';
$accessToken = 'b41sqrw1cfqh598yfoygd836c4ll3cr8';
$accessTokenSecret = 'lywj45gighqo3knl6bv6i61n2jf6iv0a';

$method = 'GET';
$url = 'http://magento.m2/index.php/rest/V1/customers/2';

//
$data = [
    'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumerKey,
    'oauth_nonce' => md5(uniqid(rand(), true)),
    'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
    'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
    'oauth_token' => $accessToken,
    'oauth_version' => '1.0',
];

$data['oauth_signature'] = sign($method, $url, $data, $consumerSecret, $accessTokenSecret);

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        'Authorization: OAuth ' . http_build_query($data, '', ',')
    ]
]);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($result);
```

**API REST using OAuth based authentication**

```
<?php
$request = new SoapClient("http://magento.m2/index.php/soap/?wsdl&services=integrationAdminTokenServiceV1", array("soap_version" => SOAP_1_2));
$token = $request->integrationAdminTokenServiceV1CreateAdminAccessToken(array("username"=>"admin", "password"=>"GN2vKgfsszz43u"));

$opts = array(
            'http'=>array(
                'header' => 'Authorization: Bearer '.json_decode($token->result)
            )
        );

$wsdlUrl = 'http://magento.m2/soap/default?wsdl&services=directoryCurrencyInformationAcquirerV1';

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, ['version' => SOAP_1_2, 'context' => $context]);

$soapResponse = $soapClient->__getFunctions();
```

**API SOAP using Token based authentication**

```
<?php
$userData = array("username" => "admin", "password" => "mypassword");
$ch = curl_init("http://magento.m2/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CUsRLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));

$token = curl_exec($ch);

$ch = curl_init("http://magento.m2/index.php/rest/V1/customers/1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Not test yet]

You should try with GET:

> http://{magento_host}/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_g‌​roups][0][filters][0‌​][field]=status&
>   searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=pending&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]‌​=eq

- Search using REST APIs: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/webapi/search-criteria.html
- OAuth-based authentication: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-oauth.html

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying. Pls check my updated question...

Comment: Changed. but still the same error.

Comment: You should check http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/24161/33057

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (I edited my code a little to show):

```
// First log in
$url = 'http://[your-domain]/rest/V1/integration/admin/token';
$body = '{"username":"user", "password":"pass"}';
$header = 'Content-type: application/json';
$options = [    'method' => 'POST',
                'content' => $body,
                'header' => $header
           ];
$context = stream_context_create(['http' => $options]);
$token = json_decode(file_get_contents($url, false, $context));

// Some settings

$header = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token . "\r\n"
    . 'Content-type: application/json';
$options = [    'method' => 'GET',
                'content' => $body,
                'header' => $header
           ];
$context = stream_context_create(['http' => $options]);

$url = 'http://[your-domain]/index.php/rest/V1/orders/'
    . '?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=status&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=pending'
    //. '&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=increment_id' // To sort Desc
    . '&fields=items[increment_id,entity_id]';

//print file_get_contents($url, false, $context) . "\n"; // Check full json if you want

// Generate json output
$json_contents = file_get_contents($url, false, $context) . "\n";
$order = json_decode($json_contents);
$answer = '{';
if ($order->items) { 
    foreach($order->items as $key => $value) {
        $answer .= '"'. $value->entity_id . '":"' . $value->increment_id . '",';
    }
    $answer = substr($answer,0,strlen($answer)-1);
    $answer .= '}';
    echo $answer;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Gediminas for your answer. I wanted to use  $consumerKey and   $consumerSecret approach to login to Magento 2. I tried with username and password approach. It works fine for me too. Just wondering why its not working with this method.

Answer (score 0):

Use swagger instead of this.

Examples:

- my [generation of swagger](https://packagist.org/packages/springimport/swagger-magento2-client);
- my [api library](https://packagist.org/packages/springimport/magento2-api-v1).