# How to build Magento 2 rest API for product info using SKU

Tags: magento2, product, api

i am learning Magento 2 but i don't know how to create API for product info and am getting error while trying

This page contains the following errors:

> Error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
>   Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Comment: Welcome to Magento StackExchange, @Sureka.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to "build" an API. Magento built-in API can perform your task already.

Ref: http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html#!/catalogProductRepositoryV1/catalogProductRepositoryV1GetGet

Comment: I need to create custom api for product info using Sku in magento2

Comment: This one is for M2 already.

Comment: I need code for product info custom api using sku,magento 2

Comment: You can check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/165825/magento-2-rest-api-how-do-i-get-pending-orders-using-api/ It's about order info, but you may find some useful logic.

Comment: i don't need oauth based athentication